# Not able to start Tridion Cache Channel Service - R5.3

Tags: cache-channel-service, r5

I am working with Tridion R5.3 GA. We are using a load balanced environment on Production consisting of 3 servers. All of them were using Tridion Cache Channel service effectively and without any issue.

However, on one of these server, the Tridion Cache Channel service comes in a stopped mode (After a scheduled maintenance and restart by the data center). While on other two server we can see the service running and even we can successfully Stop and Start the service; on a specific server, we could not start the service and see the below error while we try to start:

[image]

Following is what I have analyzed so far:

- In the event log, there is no error (Application as well as Tridion CM event log)
- If I try to further dig using `SC Query` command, then I can see the generic error as below:
  [image]
- I further verify in the Registry and can see the correct path of the `cd_cacheservice.exe`
- Already tried by restarting every service and even after the System Reboot

Can someone help and let me know what else I can verify.

Comment: its strange, No log at all, without any message, it would be difficult to find any solution. do you have option of re-installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it resolved and thanks to [Nuno Linhares](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares) for the valuable suggestion to start at the right place.

I have tried executing the java version of the cache channel service using below command:

```
java -cp cd_core.jar com.tridion.cache.CacheChannelService
```

on the Command line by navigating to the `lib` folder of my Tridion setup.

It gave me further detailed error message which get decoded to the fact that the default port used by Tridion Cache Channel Service (port 1099) has been assigned to some other process. Resolving this port conflict resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

The error message that you have is fairly generic. Is there any more information in the Deployer log file?

You may want to check:

- That the Deployer config file is valid XML, and that the settings are correct.
- The cd_license.xml file is valid (and in date) for that server. Has the machine been renamed, or the hardware (number of CPUs) been changed at all
- Is the path to the license file correct in the Deployer config file?
- Are you running on a supported version of Java (incl. 32 / 64 bit)?

Comment: Thanks Jon. Verified all these; all as per the expectations